# How does Google recognizes adult content with safesearch?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I am creating a search engine ( for studying ) and I want to know how Google recognizes adult content and images with Safesearch ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safesearch ).

The program language doesn't matter, I want to know only the approach for a generic program language.

Comment: Who's voting to close this for being too localised? How is it too localised?

Comment: If the language doesn't matter, why have you tagged this with two language tags?

Comment: @sbi: *maybe* these are his favourite languages. I would retag them but I prefer waiting for his action ;)

Comment: @djechelon Well I retagged, as OP clearly said language doesn't matter. For reference it was tagged C++ and PHP.

Comment: C++ and PHP are the languages that I know but doens't matter :)

Comment: @sbi Merged them back. We edited 4 seconds apart. :-/

Comment: @marcog: <quote>too localized --
This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific moment in time**, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.</quote>  Do you think one of the other reasons better expresses "This question should be closed because it encourages immature speculation about the trade secrets of a particular company."?  I guess we could instead apply the tag `jon-skeet-could-tell-you-but-then-he'd-have-to-kill-you`.

Comment: @Ben Not going to argue, but that conclusion is a bit ridiculous. Interpret OPs question as "ideas for implementing a safesearch-like algorithm" and it's an extremely reasonable question that's in noway localised to a specific moment in time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the rules for any sort of content filter fell into the hands of people trying to get that content through the filter, the filter would become ineffective.

So I imagine that Google's rules (1) are not publicly available and (2) change frequently.

That said, starting with a small blacklist of adult sites and following outgoing links (and/or finding sites with links to the blacklisted sites) probably finds a huge number of adult sites.  But by no means all, you'd want some sort of text processing and image recognition algorithms in addition.

NOTE: A popular theory is that adult content providers pay people to ask questions on stackoverflow.com so that Jon Skeet and Marc Gravell will have less time to update the SafeSearch filters.  However, it is easily shown that Jon and Marc answer questions at such a high rate that any such strategy would not be economically viable.

Comment: **Next question:** What algorithm has proven useful in generating stackoverflow questions that Jon Skeet and Marc Gravell will answer?

Comment: @Xeoncross: Their profile pages show that applying one of the tags `c#`, `.net`, `java`, and `linq` is likely to work.  Using more than one of these tags may yield even better results, or may cause your computer to be hacked and incorporated into the google borg cloud.  Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

Ben's answer is correct about all points, but I would like to add my considerations.

About image recognition: you will find pretty easy, given a large set of images, to identify objects like naked breasts, penises and such inside of them using pattern recognition.

All artificial intelligence algorithms, however, have weak points. You might experience that a certain percentage of your images, depending on the quality of the classificator used, is misclassified.

**Then**, you have to apply other criteria more than image processing. Surely Google's criteria are not public, but you would like to consider ICRA tags for volountarily marking certain material as adult material, text processing and *cross-domain* links. If I was the creator of the Safesearch, I would have adopted the following pattern: adult sites often exchange links, so you'll find lots of intersections in the link graphs between a group of adult sites.

Putting it all together, a good classification approach uses several *smaller* criteria, **scoring** them to determine whether an image is an adult image or not.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly in a similar way to how spam is filtered.

First step is to create a training set, based on known adult sites, and extract features from them. These could be keywords, colors used in images, domain name structure, whois details, whatever. Anything that could in some way be specifically different for adult content as compared to non-adult content.

Next step is to apply some sort of statistical model to that. Bayesian models seem to work well for spam, but may not for adult stuff.

[Support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) seem like a good fit, but that's a lot more complex and I'm not really familiar with it myself.